# ASP.NET Webform jQuery Select2 Remote Data Access

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, webforms, jquery-select2

Since last 2 days i am trying to achieve the functionality for the jQuery Select2 Remote data access from my web service. I am using ASP.NET Web form application and Webservice, following are my WebForm and WebService, I am not getting any data from my Web services, Please help

**Default.aspx**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script src="js/select2.js"></script>
    <link href="css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#ddStudents').select2({
                placeholder: "Search Student",
                minimumInputLength: 3,
                multiple: false,
                ajax: {
                    url: "StudentWebService.asmx/GetStudentSearch",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
                    quietMillis: 100,
                    data: function (term, page) {
                        return {
                            q: term,
                            page_limit: 10
                        };
                    },
                    results: function (data, page) {
                        return { results: data };
                    }
                }
            });

        });
    </script>


</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div> 
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddStudents" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select Student</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**StudentWebService.asmx**

```
  using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
    using System.Web.Services;



public class Student
{
    public string StudentID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

}

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for StudentWebService
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class StudentWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        private string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["JobPortalConnectionString"].ConnectionString;


        [WebMethod]
        public void GetStudentSearch(string term)
        {

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            try
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandText = "SelectStudentsSerach";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FirstName", term));


                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    connection.Open();
                DataSet dSet = new DataSet();
                SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter;
                sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    connection.Open();

                sqlAdapter.SelectCommand = command;
                sqlAdapter.Fill(dSet);

                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    connection.Close();


                List<Student> listStudent = new List<Student>();

                if (dSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow item in dSet.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        Student s = new Student();
                        s.StudentID = item["StudentID"].ToString();
                        s.FirstName = item["FirstName"].ToString();
                        s.LastName = item["LastName"].ToString();

                        listStudent.Add(s);
                    }
                }

                JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

                Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(listStudent));

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }

        }

    }
```

Also i set my Web.Config file added the following Tag

```
 <webServices>
        <protocols>
          <add name="HttpGet"/>
          <add name="HttpPost"/>
        </protocols>
      </webServices>
```

Comment: you need to be more specific. Is the ajax call hitting webservice method? Put a breakpoint and see if it is hit.

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: Missing parameter: term.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ValueCollectionParameterReader.Read(NameValueCollection collection)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.UrlParameterReader.Read(HttpRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()

Comment: Your data is passed as  q: term,  page_limit: 10  into the webservice. I assume the select2 passes it on as json. So try changing that to  data: function (term, page) {
                        return {
                            term: _termvaluefrompage_
                        };
                    },

Comment: Select2 by default passes anything in `data` in as a query parameter. Is that what you are expecting? Or are you expecting it to be passed in a different way?

Comment: Web service working perfectly, but the data is not binding to the Select2 Dropdown. Can you please tell me what could be the problem

Comment: What do you mean by "but the data is not binding to the Select2 Dropdown"? The issue might be that you are returning `StudentId` and `FirstName`/`LastName` instead of `id` and `text`.